# c# list methods: ElementAt(index) vs Find(content)

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am currently building a data structure which relies a lot on efficiency.

Can anyone provide me with resources on how the Find(item => item.X = myObject.Property) method actually works?
Does it iterate linearly throughout all elements until it finds the element?

And what if I know the index of myObject and I use ElementAt(index)?

Which will be the most efficient of these two please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`MSDN documentation on List<T>.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx)

> This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

I *imagine* that `ElementAt` is optimized for `IList` and will do a direct index. But since you're apparently using this object from the `List` concrete type anyway, why not just do a direct index? Like this:

```
var result = list[index];
```

If you already know the index, there is no point to searching. Just go straight to it.

Comment: ElementAt attempts to cast the collection to an IList, if that succeeds it returns the element at the requested index.  If not, it will use an enumerator